# MVVMでのListBoxItemのダブルクリックCommadの指定方法

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPFのListBoxでMVVM的なイベント追加をしたいと思っています。
そこで、ListBoxのアイテムにダブルクリックイベントをCommandを使用して追加しました。
以下の様な形で実装できたのですが、もう少しコンパクトな形にできないでしょうか？

・ItemsSourceを使用する
・ListBoxのアイテム行のどこをダブルクリックしてもイベントが発生する
　（TextBlockにイベントをつけたら文字の部分しかダメでした）
・Commandのパラメータにはダブルクリックしたアイテムが入る
の条件を満たせれば構わないのでアドバイスお願いします。

ListBox

```
<ListBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding ソース}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding 表示文字}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

リソース部分

```
<local:RestorableWindow.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <!-- 追加部分　ここから -->
                    <Border.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.ダブルクリックイベント, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Border.InputBindings>
                    <!-- ここまで -->
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: 添付プロパティやビヘイビアを定義すれば良いのでは

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いろいろ試しましたが、こんな形で落ち着きました。

```
public class DoubleClickBehavior {
    public static ICommand GetCommand( DependencyObject obj ) {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue( CommandProperty );
    }

    public static void SetCommand( DependencyObject obj, object value ) {
        obj.SetValue( CommandProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "Command", typeof( ICommand ), typeof( DoubleClickBehavior ), new UIPropertyMetadata( null, OnCommandPropertyChanged ) );

    static void OnCommandPropertyChanged( DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
        var control = depObj as Control;
        if( control == null )
            return;

        if( e.NewValue is ICommand == false )
            return;

        control.MouseDoubleClick += control_MouseDoubleClick;
    }

    static void control_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ) {
        var control = (Control)sender;
        ICommand command = DoubleClickBehavior.GetCommand( control );
        if( command != null && command.CanExecute( DoubleClickBehavior.GetCommandParameter( control ) ) ) {
            command.Execute( DoubleClickBehavior.GetCommandParameter( control ) );
        }
    }

    public static object GetCommandParameter( DependencyObject obj ) {
        return obj.GetValue( CommandParameterProperty );
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter( DependencyObject obj, object value ) {
        obj.SetValue( CommandParameterProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "CommandParameter", typeof( object ), typeof( DoubleClickBehavior ), new UIPropertyMetadata( null ) );

}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ソース}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding 表示文字}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:DoubleClickBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.DoubleClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="local:DoubleClickBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding .}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

既に挙げられている方法以外では、Blend SDKを使う方法が一番スマートそうです。
(普通のビヘイビアでもいいと思います)

まず、`Border`等の`XXXDoubleClick`系イベントを持たないControlはXAML上でダブルクリックを検出できないので、`System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior`を適当に継承して以下のようなビヘイビアを作成します。

```cs
public class DoubleClickBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DoubleClickBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(DoubleClickBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += onMouseButtonDown;
    }

    private void onMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount != 2)
            return;

        if (this.Command == null)
            return;

        if(this.Command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
        {
            this.Command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

あとは単純にXAML上で以下のように使えば動くかと。
※外見系の実装は全て省略しています

```xml
<ListBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding ソース}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Background="Red">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <v:DoubleClickBehavior Command="{Binding DataContext.DoubleClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding 表示文字}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```